# WearableListenerService doesn't receive data

Tags: wear-os

I'm trying to send sensor data from my wear device to the handheld. The problem is that the `onMessageReceived` function of my `WearableListenerService` is never called, even though it gets created.
The package names of the wear and mobile apps are the same, also here's the entry for the service in the manifest file:

```
<service
    android:name=".WatchDataReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>
```

On my handheld in the MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startService(new Intent(this, WatchDataReceiver.class));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        ...
}
```

On my handheld, the service:

```
public class WatchDataReceiver extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(WatchDataReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "WEAR create");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
        Log.i(WatchDataReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "WEAR Data changed " );
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Log.i(WatchDataReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "WEAR Message " + messageEvent.getPath());
    }
}
```

On the watch/wear:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Watch: ";

    private SensorManager   sensorManager;
    private Sensor          accelerometer;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private String msg = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        });

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        if (accelerometer != null) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Accelerometer registered!");
        }
        else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Accelerometer _not_ registered!");
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && event.values.length > 0) {
            double value_x = event.values[0];
            double value_y = event.values[1];
            double value_z = event.values[2];

            msg = Double.toString(value_x) + ";" + Double.toString(value_y) + ";" + Double.toString(value_z);
            sendMessageToHandheld(msg);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        //TODO
    }

    private void sendMessageToHandheld(String msg) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
            return;

        final String message = msg;

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"sending a message to handheld: "+message);

        // use the api client to send the heartbeat value to our handheld
        final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient);
        nodes.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result) {
                final List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++) {
                        final Node node = nodes.get(i);
                        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), message, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

According to LogCat the correct handheld is found because in `sendMessageToHandheld` right after the actual `sendMessage` it do a Log.d with the name of the node.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this `IntentFilter` to your service:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
</intent-filter>
```

It tells the system to take care of the `Service` lifecycle (ie starting it if needed).

Comment: Thanks alot, that worked. Even though I don't (yet) understand, why this is needed. The documentation says differently.

Comment: It's needed to let the System manage the service (start it for example)

Comment: com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER is now deprecated, but without it no message received...